# makefile bash recipe - include file if exists at recipe time

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a makefile that runs some custom tools. One of those tools sometimes spits out an extra file. That file must be used in a subsequent recipe (if it exists). I can't assume it exists in the dependencies, but I must use add it to the subsequent recipe command if it is there. Here's how I currently handle it:

```
final_recipe:
 [ ! -f "maybe.file" ] || tool maybe.file ...
 [ -f "maybe.file" ] || tool ...
```

This is ugly. Any suggestions for a bash executable line where bash can evaluate whether the file exists and embed it if it does? Something more like:

```
final_recipe
 tool ([ -f "maybe.file"] ? maybe.file) ...
```

Comment: If you require that it be a bash solution, then this isn't really a makefile question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may achieve what you wanted :

```
final_recipe:
    tool $$(test -f maybe.file && echo maybe.file) ...
```

Updated upon MadScientist's comment

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the make `shell` function inside a recipe.  A recipe is already running in a shell.  It's better to use `tool $$(test -f maybe.file && echo maybe.file) ...`

Comment: @MadScientist updated. Actually, the two versions might be equivalent. Your version still spawn a subshell to do `test... echo ...`, right ?

Comment: Yes, but it's a bad idea to use make `shell` functions in a recipe.  It's not related to how many shells are run, but rather the surprising (to new users) way in which it happens.  It's better to just avoid it.  In this specific case it's equivalent but in other cases it isn't, so it should not be recommended.

Comment: As you mentioned “other cases”, can you give an example?

Comment: For example, if you write something like this: `touch maybe.file; tool $(shell test -f maybe.file && echo maybe.file) ...` it will work very differently (and probably in a confusing way) than `touch maybe.file; tool $$(test -f maybe.file && echo maybe.file) ...` (when `maybe.file` doesn't exist yet).